Handling Autofilled Form Values Before User Interaction and Understanding Browser Behavior
I’m encountering an issue with browser autofill functionality and form validation that has me puzzled. Here’s what’s happening:

Scenario:


When a form is loaded, the browser autofills the username and password fields. However, the fields are initially interpreted as empty by my validation script until there is some user interaction (like a click). After the user interacts with the page, the correct autofilled values are displayed.


Behavior:


If validation is removed and the form is submitted directly without user interaction, the backend receives the correct autofilled values.
When validation is present, the fields appear empty unless the user interacts with the page.

function handleAutofill() {
  setTimeout(() => {
      const username = document.getElementById('Username').value;
      const password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
      const submitButton = document.getElementById('ActionSubmit');
      console.log(username, " ", password); // Keeps printing empty until the user interacts (clicks on screen etc.)

      if (username && password) {
          submitButton.disabled = false;
      } else {
          submitButton.disabled = true;
      }
  }, 100); // Delay for autofill to complete
}

window.addEventListener('load', handleAutofill);
document.getElementById('Username').addEventListener('input', handleAutofill);
document.getElementById('Password').addEventListener('input', handleAutofill);

Browser-Level Issue: Is this behavior due to a browser-level security feature that delays the binding of autofilled credentials until user interaction? Does this serve as a security measure to prevent auto-filled data from being accessed before the user interacts with the page?
Programmatic Solutions: Can this issue be handled programmatically? If so, how can I ensure that the validation script correctly identifies autofilled values without requiring user interaction?
I’ve tried various methods, including using setTimeout, but the fields continue to be interpreted as empty until there is user interaction. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
